# Boost Build, unable to find file or target x

Tags: boost-build

I have a Jamroot file which looks a bit like this;

```
project foo ;

alias bar ./src/path/to/bar//bar
build-project bar ;
```

Always gives the annoying error

```
error: Unable to find file or target named
error:     '/foo//bar/'
error: referred from project at
error:     '.'
```

Running with;

```
bjam --debug-building
building project Jamfile</home/chris/code/foo>  ('object(project-target)@163') with
{.. as above ...}
```

No help at all.

If I change directory into the folder and type bjam,  that part of the project builds perfectly.

As a workaround I have a script that does this in all the folders, but I would love to know why the 'proper' way doesn't work.

I'm using the following version of bjam

```
bjam --version
Boost.Build V2 (Milestone 12)
Boost.Jam 03.1.16
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have discovered that I don't actually need to do this; simply listing the sub projects as aliases in the Jamroot is enough to get bjam to build them.

So the **build-project** steps are unneeded and wrong.

I also found this from [Boost build reference page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/bbv2/reference.html);

*build-project; Cause some other project to be built. This rule takes a single parameter—a directory name relative to the containing Jamfile. When the containing Jamfile is built, the project located at that directory will be built as well. At the moment, the parameter to this rule should be a directory name. **Project ID or general target references are not allowed.***"  (my highlighting)

Comment: How do you list sub project as alias? I have this exact same problem with a nested project structure , where I want to build a subproject, that cannot "see" the requirements already declared in the parent

Comment: Yes, I had the same: how do you list sub project as alias? So, in https://github.com/wallix/redemption, there is a subfolder with `projects/qtclient/Jamroot`; I tried to make this a part of the main build with `build-project projects/qtclient` in `./Jamroot` and it kept failing with "ERROR: rule "setvar" unknown in module" (which is otherwise in .jam in qtclient directlory); then I removed that, and added `projects/qtclient` at the end (before the semicolon) of the existing `alias exe ... ;` line - and it fails the same again. So ... how?